# GetCustomAttributes from dynamically loaded Assembly

Tags: c#, attributes, load, .net-assembly

I essentially want to do this:

```
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("DataSpecDomain");
Assembly dataSpecAssembly = domain.Load(fullAssemblyFilePath);
object[] dataSpecAttrCollection = dataSpecAssembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataSpecificationAttribute), true);
```

Actually, previously I didn't have the AppDomain portion and was using Assembly.LoadFrom() which evidently is not so recommended these days in lieu of security.  The problem with this code is the assemblies I am loading into this new domain are built with their own references to a third-party API.  In fact, the third-party API references are only shell-representation of the actuals which lie in the third-party exe directory.  When referencing these, Copy Local is set to False.  The end result is that I get a FileLoadException.  If I add the shell references to the Debug folder, it works.  Is there a way I can get the attribute instances without having to deal with the loading assembly's dependencies?  Or is there a way to resolve the loading assembly's dependencies without having to place the third-party API references in the same folder.

Just for reference, the third-party product is designed with a special directory used for auto-loading, meaning that the typical development shouldn't need their references in the same folder.

Comment: Maybe [ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.reflectiononlyloadfrom(v=vs.110).aspx) might help here?

Comment: @steve16351: I've tried looking at that, but can't seem to get it to work.  So far I basically end up in the same spot.

Comment: What about handling the [assemblyresolve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the app domain and helping it find the references needed, from their original locations?